# Gitlab project visibility issue

Tags: gitlab

I want to share code with a teacher, but I simply can't make the project public. Initially I create a public one, but as it was created, it becomes private for some reason. And in general settings I can't chose 'public' or 'protected', buttons are just grey.
p.s. I don't think I need to attach any code, becase project isn't public from the very beginning. But if you want to, no problems

Also googled it, the guy said "The repo was being pushed to a new “private-only” project and not the public on", but again project isn't public from the moment of creation. Doesn't matter I chose to create public or private, it is always private -_-

Answer (score 2):

I think I know why. The problem is because the group which you are under, which is usually your name, and the group visibility is under private, thus there is a group-level restrictions on the projects. You need to go to your userId under group and select settings > general > then change the visibility of the group to public. Now you can create public projects.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to make your Project public, to invite your Teacher or someone else to see your Code.

You can invite him by his E-Mail.

For this - go into your GitLab Project, in the Menu Bar Left, click on "Members" and at the right of the Screen you will see a Button "Invite members"

[image]

Anyway - if you still wan't to make your Project Public, you should actually be able, to set the Project to Public in the Settings, if you are Maintainer/Owner (and don't forget to press "Save")